# Mongodb Update Query Deletes All Array Fields Except Field Specified in Command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Node, MongoDB, and Mongoose. I've checked the MongoDB docs on [set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) and [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/). I've Googled for a little over an hour now and I've found topics that dance around my issue, nothing definitive though.
The query below updates the correct field, but it also completely removes the other fields in the array I haven't specified.

```
db.posts.update( 
  { "_id" : { $exists : true }  },
  { $set : { userCreated : { "time" : new ISODate("2013-07-11T03:34:54Z") } } },
  false,
  true
)
```

This is the section of the schema I'm trying to modify:

```
},
userCreated: {
  id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  name: { type: String, default: '' },
  time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
},
```

This is what comes out:

```
},
"userCreated": {
  "time": { ISODate("2013-07-11T03:34:54Z") }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the `time` property of `userCreated` and leave the other properties alone by using dot notation:

```
db.posts.update( 
  { "_id" : { $exists : true }  },
  { $set : { "userCreated.time" : new ISODate("2013-07-11T03:34:54Z") } },
  false,
  true
)
```